# jest throw TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then') when trying to mock fetch request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, mocking, fetch-api

I'm trying to mock fetch request using Jest.

Here's my App.tsx

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  const [joke,setJoke] = useState("")

  useEffect(()=>{
    fetch("https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random")
    .then(res=>{
      return res.json()
    })
    .then(data=>{
      console.log("data",data)
      setJoke(data["value"])
    })
    .catch((error)=>{
      console.log("error",error)
    });
  },[])

  return (
    <div>
      {joke}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

here's my App.test.tsx

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";


global.fetch = jest.fn(()=>Promise.resolve({
  json:()=>Promise.resolve({value:"This is a test joke"})
})) as jest.Mock

describe("App",()=>{
  it("loads the joke on mount",()=>{
    const {container} = render(<App/>)
    expect(container.innerHTML).toContain("This is a test joke")
  })
})

export { };
```

i was expecting the code to run correctly, but an error is thrown: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Do you have a `jest.config.js`?

Comment: no, i dont. do i need to have one? i did have `setupTests.js` though. i initialize the project using `create-react-app`

Comment: You can try using a built-in mock for fetch instead of creating one yourself: `global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock');` I put it in my jest.setup.js I also have `import 'whatwg-fetch';` there to prevent a warning that fetch is not available.

Comment: yes, i try using a library called `jest-fetch-mock` and it works. i still wonder though why the above code doesnt work